# reference error: data is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to load an external json local file to my webpage. Im using angular1. but it gives me a reference error : data is not defined. here's the code inside my controller:

```
$scope.items = [];

$scope.loadData = function () {
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: 'joblist.json',
        data: data

    }).success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });
```

and here is my json file:

```
{"data": [{
"JobTitle": "QA Tester",
"JobCreated": "Apr 5 2018",
"JobLocation": "Pasig",
"Company": "Tencentech"
},
{
"JobTitle": "Back-End Developer",
"JobCreated": "March 19 2018",
"JobLocation": "Manila",
"Company": "Dev-Touch"
},
{
"JobTitle": "Mobile Developer",
"JobCreated": "Feb 26 2018",
"JobLocation": "Makati",
"Company": "Tose Software"
},
{
"JobTitle": "Project Manager",
"JobCreated": "Jan 8 2018",
"JobLocation": "Mandaluyong",
"Company": "Gameloft"
},
{
"JobTitle": "Accountant",
"JobCreated": "Apr 20 2018",
"JobLocation": "Taguig",
"Company": "Omnipay"
}]
}
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: The `data` in `data: data` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

`.success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.items = data.data;
    });`

Use `data.data` instead. As the object passed to `.success(function (data, status)` is response object not the data received. `responseObj.data` contains the data received.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `data:data` from your $http object

Answer (score 0):

The object that you are passing to `$http` contains a reference to a `data` object. It looks like that is not defined before you reference it. Is that the problem?

See the data variable in the following snippet

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: 'joblist.json',
    data: data

})
```